# Stuck while adding bootstrap navwalker class

Tags: menus, css, walker, twitter-bootstrap

I am stuck while adding Bootstrap Navwalker class in WordPress. All is going well, but when minimize screen to mobile view the Menu disappear. However the Search box is still showing.

[image]

header.php

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
<div class="container">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WPAcademy</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location'  => 'top-menu',
    'depth'           => 3, // 1 = no dropdowns, 2 = with dropdowns.
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
    'container_id'    => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
    'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav ml-auto',
    'fallback_cb'     => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
    'walker'          => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
) );
 ?>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

functions.php

```
// add theme options
add_theme_support('menus');

// include Bootstrap Navwalker class
if ( ! file_exists( get_template_directory() . '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php' ) ) {
    // File does not exist... return an error.
    return new WP_Error( 'class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker-missing', __( 'It appears the class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php file may be missing.', 'wp-bootstrap-navwalker' ) );
} else {
    // File exists... require it.
    require_once get_template_directory() . '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';
}

// meanus
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'top-menu' => 'Top Menu Location',
        'mobile-menu' => 'Mobile Menu Location',
        'footer-menu' => 'Footer Menu Location',
    )
);
```

Comment: if the display change with screen width, it's a CSS question.

Comment: @Kaperto It work, when I use static links